# Adding a logo in Navigation Bar that is left aligned

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have been stumped on how to get an image in a NavigationBar that is left aligned. I understand how to replace the title in the center.

Basically, I have a view controller embedded in a Navigation Bar Controller. In that view controller, I have a search form in the middle and a bar button on the right and I am trying to fit in a logo that is an image to the left side.

Below is the what I understand how to put an image but how do I get it left aligned?

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
let image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
imageView.image = image
navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can assign an array of items to the `leftBarButtonItems` property of the `navigationBar`. You should add an array because there is usually no space between the left side and the logo, and this doesn't look great. Here is an example:

```
func setUpUI() {
    let logoImage = UIImage.init(named: "logoImage")
    let logoImageView = UIImageView.init(image: logoImage)
    logoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(-40, 0, 150, 25)
    logoImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    let imageItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: logoImageView)
    let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    negativeSpacer.width = -25
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer, imageItem]
}
```

The negative spacer to the left of it will push it over a bit, and you can adjust it from there.

Comment: This is awesome. Worked perfectly. The negative spacer was a great idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

For iOS 11 we need to add constraints to the image view  of the BarButtomItem

```
 func addLeftBarIcon(named:String) {

    let logoImage = UIImage.init(named: named)
    let logoImageView = UIImageView.init(image: logoImage)
    logoImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,y:0.0, width:60,height:25.0)
    logoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let imageItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: logoImageView)
    let widthConstraint = logoImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
    let heightConstraint = logoImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25)
     heightConstraint.isActive = true
     widthConstraint.isActive = true
     navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =  imageItem
}
```

All the best

Answer (score 0):

Per @Warrior's answer,

For **Objective-C**, iOS11+ and relative layout for the logo.

```
    // create Youtube icon imageView
    UIImageView *youtubeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    youtubeImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    youtubeImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    youtubeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"youtube_icon"];
    UIBarButtonItem *imageItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:youtubeImageView];
    
    // set constraints
    float width = self.view.frame.size.width * 0.3;
    float height = width * 178 / 794; // width * 1/ratio

    [youtubeImageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:width].active = true;
    [youtubeImageView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:height].active = true;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = imageItem;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Create a BarButton item with Image.

Assign it as Left Bar Button Item to Navigation Bar as follows.

**Objective C**

```
UIBarButtonItem *logo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"imageName"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(methodName)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logo;
```

**SWIFT**

```
let logo = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage (named: "imageName"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: methodName)

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logo
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: In the Objective-C example, shouldn't the style be UIBarButtonItemStylePlain...?

Comment: Yes @JoshB Updated answer above.